# Consider the sequence $x_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}$ and $y_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Consider the sequence

$\begin{align}
  & {{x}_{n}}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{j}} \\ 
 & {{y}_{n}}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{{{j}^{2}}}} \\ 
\end{align}$

Then

$\{{{x}_{n}}\}$ is Cauchy but $\{{{y}_{n}}\}$is not.

what I tried to show that $x_n$ is convergent by monotonic bounded. But I could not show that $x_n$ is bounded. Dont know about $y_n$

Comment: You have it backwards: the harmonic series diverges, so $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ diverges and therefore is **not** Cauchy. $\sum_{j\ge 1}\frac1{j^2}$, on the other hand converges, so its sequence of partial sums **is** Cauchy.

Comment: You have it backwards -- $\{ y_n \}$ is cauchy (indeed it is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) to converge to $\pi^2/6$) whereas $\{ x_n \}$ is _not_ cauchy (it is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) to diverge)

Comment: How to prove $y_n$ bounded?

Comment: @user124717 Do you know the fact that a sequence of real numbers if Cauchy if and only if it is convergent? Then you need to recognize the series above as the harmonic series, which is known to be *divergent*, and the second is the reciprocal-of-squares series, which is known to be *convergent* (for example, using the integral test). If you do not know any of these facts it will be worth looking over these in a standard textbook in real analysis or on Wikipedia and proofWiki. (You are , however, correct in observing the monotonicity, indeed boundedness is the only missing piece).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove $\{y_n\}$ is bounded, notice that $1/n^2<1/n(n-1)$ for $n\geq 2.$

So, we have that

$$\sum_1^m \frac{1}{n^2}<1+\sum_2^m \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\leq 1+1-\frac{1}{m}<2.$$

Comment: Oops, sorry, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first isn't Cauchy. Hint:
$$x_{2n} - x_n = \frac 1{n+1} + \cdots + \frac 1{2n}\ge\cdots$$
Can you continue?